# Heroku Deployment Error:can't resolve jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rubygems

I am trying to deploy this app to heroku.
i get this error with the precompiling asset pipeline.
I tried removing jquery from my Gem file but the error persists.
log:

```
...
remote:        Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap 4.4.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 71 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Post-install message from i18n:
remote:        
remote:        HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
remote:        But that may break your application.
remote:        
remote:        If you are upgrading your Rails application from an older version of Rails:
remote:        
remote:        Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
remote:        If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
remote:        'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
remote:        If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.
remote:        
remote:        If you are starting a NEW Rails application, you can ignore this notice.
remote:        
remote:        For more info see:
remote:        https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
remote:        
remote:        Post-install message from paperclip:
remote:        ##################################################
remote:        #  NOTE FOR UPGRADING FROM 4.3.0 OR EARLIER      #
remote:        ##################################################
remote:        
remote:        Paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0.
remote:        
remote:        If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few small
remote:        changes:
remote:        
remote:        * You must set the `s3_region`
remote:        * If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an initializer,
remote:          note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore to
remote:          using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
remote:          `public-read`.
remote:        
remote:        For a walkthrough of upgrading from 4 to 5 and aws-sdk >= 2.0 you can watch
remote:        http://rubythursday.com/episodes/ruby-snack-27-upgrade-paperclip-and-aws-sdk-in-prep-for-rails-5
remote:        Bundle completed (201.79s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.16.0
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        yarn install v1.16.0
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 22.87s.
remote:        yarn install v1.16.0
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.10.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 4.99s.
remote:        I, [2020-02-01T17:00:57.359431 #1789]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/public/assets/manifest-cadda289ef9c70eaa0879a36e6263cb33f7523a16b3ef862e0b8609cdc2bdab1.js
remote:        I, [2020-02-01T17:00:57.360167 #1789]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/public/assets/manifest-cadda289ef9c70eaa0879a36e6263cb33f7523a16b3ef862e0b8609cdc2bdab1.js.gz
remote:        I, [2020-02-01T17:00:57.361753 #1789]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/public/assets/jumbo-5e6e2f89b0d4b9202695b50c7ec76d6bf3fc95738bbe4e0d6215f671d270aed5.jpg
remote:        I, [2020-02-01T17:00:57.367166 #1789]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/public/assets/application-0d811fde68f44a2659d7cfeb78037b71d64cc26f7043db7ba50822feb5ad7db3.css
remote:        I, [2020-02-01T17:00:57.369678 #1789]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/public/assets/application-0d811fde68f44a2659d7cfeb78037b71d64cc26f7043db7ba50822feb5ad7db3.css.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in '/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/packs
remote:            at factory.create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10)
remote:            at factory (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22)
remote:            at resolver (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
remote:            at asyncLib.parallel (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
remote:            at /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
remote:            at /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
remote:            at normalResolver.resolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
remote:            at doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn41 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:28:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn1 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at args (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:            at resolver.doResolve (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn42 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
remote:            at hook.callAsync (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5)
remote:            at _fn0 (eval at create (/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
remote:        resolve 'jquery' in '/tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/packs'
remote:          Parsed request is a module
remote:          using description file: /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
remote:            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:            resolve as module
remote:              looking for modules in /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript
remote:                using description file: /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
remote:                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                  using description file: /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/jquery)
remote:                    no extension
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery doesn't exist
remote:                    .mjs
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.mjs doesn't exist
remote:                    .js
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.js doesn't exist
remote:                    .sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.module.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.module.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.module.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .png
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.png doesn't exist
remote:                    .svg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.svg doesn't exist
remote:                    .gif
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.gif doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpeg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.jpeg doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery.jpg doesn't exist
remote:                    as directory
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/jquery doesn't exist
remote:              /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/packs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /tmp/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
remote:              looking for modules in /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules
remote:                using description file: /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
remote:                  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                  using description file: /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
remote:                    no extension
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery doesn't exist
remote:                    .mjs
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.mjs doesn't exist
remote:                    .js
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.js doesn't exist
remote:                    .sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.sass
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.module.sass doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.scss
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.module.scss doesn't exist
remote:                    .module.css
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.module.css doesn't exist
remote:                    .png
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.png doesn't exist
remote:                    .svg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.svg doesn't exist
remote:                    .gif
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.gif doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpeg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.jpeg doesn't exist
remote:                    .jpg
remote:                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery.jpg doesn't exist
remote:                    as directory
remote:                      /tmp/build_76a7760f35cf1fa7ba2c91624cad2766/node_modules/jquery doesn't exist
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to unige.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/unige.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/unige.git'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem "paperclip", "~> 6.0.0"
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

here is my application.html.erb: (because it has the jquery and bootstrap links)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/579c92a99f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="alert-success" >
      <%= notice %>
    </div>

    <div class="alert-success" >
      <%= alert %>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have i missed something? do i need to require jquery in my javascript asset folder ?

Comment: Could you please post your application.js as well?

Comment: hey @masaaki i deleted this file. it seems like some files have been deleted along the way which caused this error, because i started the website from scratch again and it worked. thank you for trying to help though. if you don't mind please have a look at my last question. maybe you could help!